# How to define degrees of freedom in eBayes function

Tags: r, analysis, bioconductor, limma

I am using Bioconductor `limma` package. I want to define degree of freedom in `eBayes` function for microarray analysis.  How can I change default degrees of freedom in it? Pleasee see the code below:

```
fit2 <- eBayes(fit2, 0.01)
```

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Bioinformatics-specific questions may be better received on [Bioconductor Support](https://support.bioconductor.org/)

Answer (score 0):

However the reason to change degrees of freedom after modeling is unclear, as degrees of freedom characterize the amount of variables and observations in your input data. You can change the degrees of freedom of the `MArrayLM` object, which is an argument of `eBayes` function.
Please see the code below:

```
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("limma", suppressUpdates = TRUE)

library(limma)
set.seed(123)
sigma2 <- 0.05 / rchisq(100, df = 10) * 10
y <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 6, sd = sqrt(sigma2)), 100, 6)
design <- cbind(Intercept=1, Group=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
y[1, 4:6] <- y[1, 4:6] + 1
fit <- lmFit(y, design)

fit$df.residual
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# [63] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

fit$df.residual <- rep(3, 100)

#  Moderated t-statistic
fit <- eBayes(fit, .01)
```